QEMU arch-chroot using external custom kernel
I've made an ArchLinux RootFS for zynqmp like here. But I haven't installed kernel inside RootFS and deleted hte one which is default, as I want to change kernels frequently, so I've placed it in BOOT partition of my SD.
Now I want to chroot in this environment from my x86-64 linux PC, but as there is no kernel inside, I cannot do some things as environment errors me about different security policies that are not present in kernel. Is there any way I can point qemu on my custom kernel with chroot?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Generally speaking, chroot operates by using the running kernel with a new filesystem root. However, the linked repository contains the highly specialized embedded solution with very specific setup, using QEMU userspace emulator, u-boot and specific firmware. I suggest asking the developer if what is wanted is possible and how.

so chroot with qemu-binfmt uses kernel from x86-64 translating arm64 commands from that environment?
